# How to select only first 100 rows on Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have gridview that contains check boxes in one of the columns, then there is a "Select ALl" button which when clicked has to check top 100 CBs on the list, the client specifically stated they do not want pagination, it much easier to do this with pagination and display only 100 records per page then when the select all button is clicked everything on the given page gets selected however this is not what the client wants

Here is my code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgridTransactions.Rows)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <=100;x++ )
    {
        var oneTransaction = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAssigned");
        oneTransaction.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you use `javascript` or `jquery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue in your code
You can use the below code

```
int x=0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgridTransactions.Rows)
{
    if(x<100 )
    {
        var oneTransaction = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAssigned");
        oneTransaction.Checked = true;
    }
    else
        break;
    x++;
}
```

The `foreach (GridViewRow row in dgridTransactions.Rows)` loop runs for each row in your grid.

and in that you are using `for (int x = 0; x <=100;x++ ){` which runs 100 times for every row.

You can use jquery or javascript for this Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Q6SxW/) which can help you

Comment: Thank you for your response, very informative, I'll keep the JSFiggle in my notes for future use as the first answer already helped me, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run first hundred rows you only need this loop

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    GridViewRow row = dgridTransactions.Rows[x];
    // then manage row properties
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAssigned");
    cb.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking, thank you so much you are a life saver

Comment: apologies, because of reputation constraints :) I am unable to up-vote your answer

Answer (score 1):

using RowIndex you can keep track of row number.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgridTransactions.Rows)
{
    if(row.RowIndex<100 )
    {
        var oneTransaction = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAssigned");
        oneTransaction.Checked = true;
    }
    else
        break;

}
```

Comment: Remember Index starts with 0 so it should be `<100`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgridTransactions.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Take(100)) {
    CheckBox cb = row.FindControl("chkAssigned") as CheckBox;
    if (cb != null)
      cb.Checked = true;
  }
```

This will give the first items up to 100, so if you only have 90, it will give 90.
The diferent way of casting will also give you an additional security measure in case it fails to find the control. A direct cast will just throw an exception, which is always heavier then checking if the castes object is not null...

If you dont care about the cast verification, you can just inline everything into this:

```
dgridTransactions.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Take(100).ToList().ForEach(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl()).Checked = true);
```